# How to use variables from another file for Pytest

Tags: python, pygame, pytest

I want to set up some unit tests for my game in `Fish.py`, and make sure that when the game plays through several different sessions the tests are always clear. I put my unit tests into `FishTests.py`. In this small example, the score counter should never be negative.

```py
import pytest
import Fish

# TEST: counter should never be negative
def test_counter_neg(Fish.counter):
    assert counter > 0
```

My IDE Pycharm underlines `Fish.counter` in red and gives an error `Unresolved reference`.

What's the right way to do this? Am I supposed to use the `fixture`? But then I'd need to write a new fixture for every variable and function from `Fish.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume Fish is a class, not an object. You should write a fixture for each of your sessions. Let the fixture create a Fish object, run the session, and provide that object to the test functions.